# How to get w3c Logo

Tags: web, html, w3c

I want to certify my website webpage and put w3c logo.can I simply put the w3c logo after validation? or what else does it take?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to verify a whole site at once.  If you run individual pages through the validator and they pass it will give you instructions on how to display w3c logos, make them into links that allow re-validating the page and so on.

Comment: I know of one that will validate up to 100 pages spidered from whatever page is given as input: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/ It uses the WDG's rules, but I'm fairly sure those are close to the w3c's rules. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing technical stopping you from putting the w3c logo on some geocities page, if you like. The icon links are given to you just after you validate a page at http://validator.w3.org/.